# PostgreSQL: Modify OWNER on all tables simultaneously in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How do I modify the owner of all tables in a PostgreSQL database?

I tried `ALTER TABLE * OWNER TO new_owner` but it doesn't support the asterisk syntax.

Answer (score 548, accepted):

## See [`REASSIGN OWNED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) command

**Note:** As @trygvis [mentions in the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13535184/716118), the [`REASSIGN OWNED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) command is available since at least version 8.2, and is a much easier method.

---

Since you're changing the ownership for all tables, you likely want views and sequences too.  Here's what I did:

Tables:

```
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';" YOUR_DB` ; do  psql -c "alter table \"$tbl\" owner to NEW_OWNER" YOUR_DB ; done
```

Sequences:

```
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select sequence_name from information_schema.sequences where sequence_schema = 'public';" YOUR_DB` ; do  psql -c "alter sequence \"$tbl\" owner to NEW_OWNER" YOUR_DB ; done
```

Views:

```
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select table_name from information_schema.views where table_schema = 'public';" YOUR_DB` ; do  psql -c "alter view \"$tbl\" owner to NEW_OWNER" YOUR_DB ; done
```

You could probably [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) that up a bit since the alter statements are identical for all three.

---

Comment: +1 Thanks Alex. I've created a little bash script based on your answer, available at https://gist.github.com/2482969

Comment: For anyone wondering why all 3 are `ALTER TABLE ... OWNER TO`, rather than `ALTER SEQUENCE ...`. In the case of sequences it's because  `ALTER SEQUENCE ... OWNED BY ...` has an entirely different meaning. The OWNED BY option causes the sequence to be associated with a specific table column, such that if that column (or its whole table) is dropped, the sequence will be automatically dropped as well. ... Specifying OWNED BY NONE removes any existing association, making the sequence "free-standing".

Comment: See the recent answer by @trygvis. Simplest answer by far: `REASSIGN OWNED BY old_role [, ...] TO new_role`

Comment: REASSIGN OWNED BY doesn't work for objects owned by postgres.

Comment: This only alters tables, sequences, and views in the `public` schema. If you use other schemas, then this won't work :(

Comment: Also, REASSIGN OWNED actually affects the ownership of all databases owned by the old role (See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-reassign-owned.html). So if you only want to change the ownership of a single database, beware!

Comment: Don't forget the functions. As @AlannaRose said in another answer's comment, look at: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803096/how-to-alter-owner-of-a-function-in-postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803096/how-to-alter-owner-of-a-function-in-postgres)

Comment: Based on @gingerlime script, bspkrs (couldn't find his name) created one that also changes the functions: [https://gist.github.com/bspkrs/b997ed7f1eb1268f3403](https://gist.github.com/bspkrs/b997ed7f1eb1268f3403)

Comment: For anyone like me who is new to psql command line, here is how you can set host and user name for the above commands: for tbl in `psql -U USERNAME -h 127.0.0.1 -qAt -c "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';" dbname` ; do  psql -U USERNAME -h 127.0.0.1 -c "alter table \"$tbl\" owner to new_owner" db_name; done  This will still ask for password for every table, so you can set/export password in terminal like: export PGPASSWORD=password_for_USERNAME Might help someone.

Comment: In case you have materialized views you then also need to execute

Comment: This does currently no more work with the newest git-bash on windows...

Comment: Upvoting this since [REASSIGN OWNED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) gives issues with the `Superuser` role owning `system` relationships

Comment: I come to this answer several times per year, thank you

Comment: @kitsune, from my test and the link you provide in your comment, REASIGN OWNED affects only the **current database**. Is it a mistake ? Could you elaborate ? What you mean by all databases owned by the old role ?

Answer (score 632):

You can use the [`REASSIGN OWNED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) command.

### Synopsis:

> ```
> REASSIGN OWNED BY old_role [, ...] TO new_role
> ```

This changes all objects owned by `old_role` to the new role. You don't have to think about what kind of objects that the user has, they will all be changed. Note that it only applies to objects inside a single database. It does not alter the owner of the database itself either.

It is available back to at least 8.2. Their online documentation only goes that far back.

Comment: `ERROR:  unexpected classid 3079`. I guess that doesn't currently work if there are any extensions.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for user postgres, even though I am connected to a database that I created (i.e. not a system database), it says this:
ERROR:  cannot reassign ownership of objects owned by role postgres because they are required by the database system

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reassign ownership of objects that's internal to postgresql, like the pg_* tables/views.

Comment: As @thnee reported, REASSIGN affects all objects in the database and it doesn't discriminate between user defined and system objects, so it doesn't work for postgres if there are any extension having their own tables. Still I prefer (+1) this option for elegance, even though it didn't help me much (my database was previously owned by postgres).

Comment: Just to be clear, this command works in the database that you are currently connected ONLY. If the old_role owns objects in multiple databases, you should connect and run this command in each one of those databases

Comment: This is very helpful in cases where you want to move all objects (as the OP requested). It is not helpful if you want to reassign ownership of a subset of objects ( 6 of 10 tables in public to a managed schema). I that case the original accepted answer has the greater value.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on postgres hosted via AWS RDS. I'm getting this error "permission denied to reassign objects" and this link suggests why: "It would appear that the only way to 'reassign owned' is as a superuser (which is contradicted by the documentation), which isn't accessible in RDS.' http://www.postgresql-archive.org/REASSIGN-OWNED-simply-doesn-t-work-td5987901.html

Comment: How do you even use it? I have entered it and nothing has changed

Comment: Also in GCP when signed as "postgres" user this doesn't work.

Answer (score 352):

This: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2007-10/msg00234.php is also a nice and fast solution, and works for multiple schemas in one database:

**Tables**

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '|| schemaname || '."' || tablename ||'" OWNER TO my_new_owner;'
FROM pg_tables WHERE NOT schemaname IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
ORDER BY schemaname, tablename;
```

**Sequences**

```
SELECT 'ALTER SEQUENCE '|| sequence_schema || '."' || sequence_name ||'" OWNER TO my_new_owner;'
FROM information_schema.sequences WHERE NOT sequence_schema IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
ORDER BY sequence_schema, sequence_name;
```

**Views**

```
SELECT 'ALTER VIEW '|| table_schema || '."' || table_name ||'" OWNER TO my_new_owner;'
FROM information_schema.views WHERE NOT table_schema IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
ORDER BY table_schema, table_name;
```

**Materialized Views**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23093450/2000654)

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '|| oid::regclass::text ||' OWNER TO my_new_owner;'
FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'm'
ORDER BY oid;
```

This generates all the required `ALTER TABLE` / `ALTER SEQUENCE` / `ALTER VIEW` statements, copy these and paste them back into plsql to run them.

Check your work in psql by doing:

```
\dt *.*
\ds *.*
\dv *.*
```

Comment: Great solution.  My only issue was that I had export the scripts and then execute the exported scripts.  I am SQL Server Guru but I am not sure what the shortcut is to execute.  I clicked execute query and execute pgScript.  What was I doing wrong?

Comment: I preferred this as it works from within plsql once logged in - the unix level scripts (currently favourite answer) require a "-U postgres" and password entry in my environment.

Comment: I prefer this answer because (1) it can be done in psql or pgAdmin (2) it easily allows you to see the objects you'll be altering. I also used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803096/how-to-alter-owner-of-a-function-in-postgres, which is similar, but for functions.

Comment: you can use this way to execute it in sql. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847819/how-to-execute-a-query-which-is-stored-in-a-table-column-postgresql

Comment: Can you Add SELECT for functions?

Comment: Please add another script for large-objects. (ALTER LARGE OBJECT large_object_oid OWNER TO { new_owner)

Answer (score 46):

If you want to do it in one sql statement, you need to define an exec() function as mentioned in http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Dynamic_DDL

```
CREATE FUNCTION exec(text) returns text language plpgsql volatile
  AS $f$
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE $1;
      RETURN $1;
    END;
$f$;
```

Then you can execute this query, it will change the owner of tables, sequences and views:

```
SELECT exec('ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(s.nspname) || '.' ||
            quote_ident(s.relname) || ' OWNER TO $NEWUSER')
  FROM (SELECT nspname, relname
          FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid) 
         WHERE nspname NOT LIKE E'pg\\_%' AND 
               nspname <> 'information_schema' AND 
               relkind IN ('r','S','v') ORDER BY relkind = 'S') s;
```

$NEWUSER is the postgresql new name of the new owner.

In most circumstances you need to be superuser to execute this. You can avoid that by changing the owner from your own user to a role group you are a member of.

Thanks to RhodiumToad on [#postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/community/irc/) for helping out with this.

Comment: This is much more useful since it changes ownership of the entire schema, including functions, indexes, sequences, etc.. Thank you!

Comment: It does not change schema owners. How to change schema owners also?

Comment: @Andrus ALTER DATABASE $DB OWNER TO $OWNER;

Comment: alter database changes whole database owner. I asked how to change schema owners.

Comment: ALTER SCHEMA fred OWNER TO betty;

Answer (score 37):

is very simple

1. `su - postgres`
2. `psql`
3. `REASSIGN OWNED BY [old_user] TO [new_user];`
4. `\c [your database]`
5. `REASSIGN OWNED BY [old_user] TO [new_user];`

done.

Comment: This _probably_ does what the querent wanted.  By far the easiest.

Comment: You're only 4 years late to the party; scroll up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13535184/1772379

Comment: @BenJohnson in this answer it doesn't explain how to use it though :/

Answer (score 31):

I like this one since it modifies **tables**, **views**, **sequences** and **functions** owner of a certain **schema** in **one go** (in one sql statement), without creating a function and you can use it directly in **PgAdmin III** and **psql**:

(Tested in PostgreSql v9.2)

```
DO $$DECLARE r record;
DECLARE
    v_schema varchar := 'public';
    v_new_owner varchar := '<NEW_OWNER>';
BEGIN
    FOR r IN 
        select 'ALTER TABLE "' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from information_schema.tables where table_schema = v_schema
        union all
        select 'ALTER TABLE "' || sequence_schema || '"."' || sequence_name || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from information_schema.sequences where sequence_schema = v_schema
        union all
        select 'ALTER TABLE "' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from information_schema.views where table_schema = v_schema
        union all
        select 'ALTER FUNCTION "'||nsp.nspname||'"."'||p.proname||'"('||pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid)||') OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from pg_proc p join pg_namespace nsp ON p.pronamespace = nsp.oid where nsp.nspname = v_schema
    LOOP
        EXECUTE r.a;
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Based on answers provided by @rkj, @AlannaRose, @SharoonThomas, @user3560574 and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22803406/2796922) by @a_horse_with_no_name

Thank's a lot.

---

Better yet: Also change **database** and **schema** owner.

```
DO $$DECLARE r record;
DECLARE
    v_schema varchar := 'public';
    v_new_owner varchar := 'admin_ctes';
BEGIN
    FOR r IN 
        select 'ALTER TABLE "' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from information_schema.tables where table_schema = v_schema
        union all
        select 'ALTER TABLE "' || sequence_schema || '"."' || sequence_name || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from information_schema.sequences where sequence_schema = v_schema
        union all
        select 'ALTER TABLE "' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from information_schema.views where table_schema = v_schema
        union all
        select 'ALTER FUNCTION "'||nsp.nspname||'"."'||p.proname||'"('||pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid)||') OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from pg_proc p join pg_namespace nsp ON p.pronamespace = nsp.oid where nsp.nspname = v_schema
        union all
        select 'ALTER SCHEMA "' || v_schema || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner 
        union all
        select 'ALTER DATABASE "' || current_database() || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner 
    LOOP
        EXECUTE r.a;
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Comment: AMAZING!  Why postgres does not add this I do not know!

Comment: Two questions: 1) It looks like the first and third "ALTER TABLE" lines are dupes. Is that intentional (e.g. do you have to do two passes over the tables to change ownership?). 2) We're finding that `information_schema.sequences` is empty even though `SELECT c.* FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';` lists sequences. Why might they not match?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the second `ALTER` query be an `ALTER SEQUENCE`?

Comment: Why are the sequence owners being updated via alter _table_ commands?

Comment: Thanks, I also use `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO <NEW_OWNER>; GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO <NEW_OWNER>; GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO <NEW_OWNER>; GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO <NEW_OWNER>;` to fix permissions for existing entities. and `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO <NEW_OWNER>; ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO <NEW_OWNER>; ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL ON FUNCTIONS TO <NEW_OWNER>;` to fix permissions on newly created entities.

Answer (score 29):

If current owner is not postgres you can use this:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY old_role [, ...] TO new_role
```

But if the current owner is postgres you definitely get error so you have to use  @dvanrensburg answer but if you want to execute commands in same sql use these command based on need:

**Database**

```
ALTER DATABASE target_database OWNER TO new_onwer;
```

**Tables**

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
DECLARE
  stmt text;
BEGIN
  FOR stmt IN
    WITH temp as (
    SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '|| schemaname || '."' || tablename ||'" OWNER TO newuser' as command
    FROM pg_tables WHERE NOT schemaname IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    ORDER BY schemaname, tablename )
    SELECT command from temp
  LOOP
    EXECUTE stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

**Sequences**

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
DECLARE
  stmt text;
BEGIN
  FOR stmt IN
    WITH temp as (
    SELECT 'ALTER SEQUENCE '|| sequence_schema || '."' || sequence_name ||'" OWNER TO newuser;' as command
    FROM information_schema.sequences WHERE NOT sequence_schema IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    ORDER BY sequence_schema, sequence_name)
    select command from temp
  LOOP
    EXECUTE stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

**Views**

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
DECLARE
  stmt text;
BEGIN
  FOR stmt IN
    WITH temp as (
    SELECT 'ALTER VIEW '|| table_schema || '."' || table_name ||'" OWNER TO newuser;' as command
    FROM information_schema.views WHERE NOT table_schema IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    ORDER BY table_schema, table_name)
    select command from temp
  LOOP
    EXECUTE stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

**Schemas**

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
DECLARE
  stmt text;
BEGIN
  FOR stmt IN
    WITH schema_names as(
    SELECT distinct(schemaname) FROM pg_tables WHERE NOT schemaname IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    ORDER BY schemaname)
    SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA '|| schemaname ||' OWNER TO newuser;' as command
    FROM schema_names
  LOOP
    EXECUTE stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Also note the functions and other components of the database that may need to change memberships

**Functions and trigger functions**

```
    DO
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    $$
    DECLARE
      stmt text;
    BEGIN
      FOR stmt IN
        WITH temp as(
        SELECT 'alter function '||nsp.nspname||'.'||p.proname||'('||pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid)||') owner to newuser;' as command
        FROM pg_proc p
        JOIN pg_namespace nsp ON p.pronamespace = nsp.oid
        WHERE NOT  nsp.nspname IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema'))
        SELECT command FROM temp
      LOOP
        EXECUTE stmt;
      END LOOP;
    END;
    $$;
```

Comment: Thanks! That's real ready-to-use code

Answer (score 24):

I recently had to change the ownership of all objects in a database. Although tables, views, triggers and sequences were somewhat easily changed the above approach failed for functions as the signature is part of the function name. Granted, I have a MySQL background and am not that familiar with Postgres.

However, **pg_dump** allows you to dump just the schema and this contains the **ALTER xxx OWNER TO yyy;** statements you need. Here is my bit of shell magic on the topic

```
pg_dump -s YOUR_DB | grep -i 'owner to' | sed -e 's/OWNER TO .*;/OWNER TO NEW_OWNER;/i' | psqL YOUR_DB
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using the `grep` command. I'm new to Linux myself, but from my understanding, it seems that `sed` is just fine to use, especially since you're specifying a case-insensitive match anyway.

Comment: grep is used here to filter the output of pg_dump to only have lines with 'owner to' which then are modified with sed. Only lines with 'owner to' will be executed and not the entire dump.

Answer (score 23):

very simple, try it...

```
 select 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' OWNER TO myuser;' from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public';
```

Comment: You might add a note that the corresponding strings have to be copied and executed. Not that it's not obvious :p

Comment: Which includes removing all the quotes around the alter statements.. multi-cursors or replace helps in this case.

Comment: Adding `\gexec` at the end of the command worked for me

`select 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' OWNER TO myuser;' from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public' \gexec`

Answer (score 18):

I had to change the ownership of tables, views and sequences and found the great solution posted by @rjk is working fine - despite one detail:
If the object names are of mixed case (e.g. "TableName"), this will fail with an "not found"-error.
To circumvent this, wrap the object names with ' " ' like this:

### Tables

```sql
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE \"'|| schemaname || '.' || tablename ||'\" OWNER TO my_new_owner;'
FROM pg_tables WHERE NOT schemaname IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
ORDER BY schemaname, tablename;
```

### Sequences

```sql
SELECT 'ALTER SEQUENCE \"'|| sequence_schema || '.' || sequence_name ||'\" OWNER TO my_new_owner;'
FROM information_schema.sequences WHERE NOT sequence_schema IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
ORDER BY sequence_schema, sequence_name;
```

### Views

```sql
SELECT 'ALTER VIEW \"'|| table_schema || '.' || table_name ||'\" OWNER TO my_new_owner;'
FROM information_schema.views WHERE NOT table_schema IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
ORDER BY table_schema, table_name;
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try the following in PostgreSQL 9

```
DO $$DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'alter table '|| r.tablename ||' owner to newowner;';
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no such command in PostgreSQL. But you can work around it using method I [described](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/10/19/grantall/) some time ago for GRANTs.

Comment: Thank you, very nice article. I will keep this as a future reference. Using pgAdmin, I ended up backing up the DB, dropping/deleting the DB, temporarily granting new_owner the necessary rights, and then re-creating and restoring DB as the new_owner, with the "no owner" option checked in the restore window. This produced the results I was looking for with new_owner as the owner of everything.

Comment: Postgres 9.3 introduced the REASSIGN OWNED command.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-reassign-owned.html

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [answer by elysch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37259655), here is a solution for multiple schemas:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
  r record;
  i int;
  v_schema text[] := '{public,schema1,schema2,schema3}';
  v_new_owner varchar := 'my_new_owner';
BEGIN
    FOR r IN 
        select 'ALTER TABLE "' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ANY (v_schema)
        union all
        select 'ALTER TABLE "' || sequence_schema || '"."' || sequence_name || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from information_schema.sequences where sequence_schema = ANY (v_schema)
        union all
        select 'ALTER TABLE "' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from information_schema.views where table_schema = ANY (v_schema)
        union all
        select 'ALTER FUNCTION "'||nsp.nspname||'"."'||p.proname||'"('||pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid)||') OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';' as a from pg_proc p join pg_namespace nsp ON p.pronamespace = nsp.oid where nsp.nspname = ANY (v_schema)
        union all
        select 'ALTER DATABASE "' || current_database() || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner 
    LOOP
        EXECUTE r.a;
    END LOOP;
    FOR i IN array_lower(v_schema,1) .. array_upper(v_schema,1)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'ALTER SCHEMA "' || v_schema[i] || '" OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner ;
    END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pg_dump as insert statements 
pg_dump -d -O database filename
-d ( data as inserts ) -O ( capital O is no owner )
```

Then pipe the backup file back in to PostgreSQL using:

```
psql -d database -U username -h hostname < filename
```

As there is no owner included then all of the created table, schema, etc,  are created under the login user you specify.

I have read this could be a good approach for migrating between PostgreSQL versions as well.

Comment: i think this is the easiest way to change ownership of everything in a db if it's small enough and dumping/restoring is an option.  however the `pg_dump` command syntax is outdated and `-d` is now `--column-inserts`, but it's not recommended for pgsql only operations.  i just use `--clean` and `--no-owner`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Alex Soto is the right one and the gist uploaded by @Yoav Aner also works provided there are no special characters in the table/view names (which are legal in postgres).

You need to escape them to work and I have uploaded a gist for that: https://gist.github.com/2911117

Answer (score 2):

I’ve created a convenient script for that; [pg_change_db_owner.sh](https://gist.github.com/jirutka/afa3ce62b1430abf7572#file-pg_change_db_owner-sh). This script change ownership for all tables, views, sequences and functions in a database schema and also owner of the schema itself.

Please note that if you wanna just change the ownership of all objects, in a particular database,
owned by a particular database role, then you can simply use command `REASSIGN OWNED` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in PostgreSQL 9.0, you have the ability to `GRANT [priv name] ON ALL [object type]  IN SCHEMA` where `[priv name]` is the typical `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc` and `[object type]` can be one of:

- `TABLES`
- `SEQUENCES`
- `FUNCTIONS`

PostgreSQL's docs on [`GRANT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) and [`REVOKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) go in to more detail regarding this. In some situations it's still required to use tricks involving the system catalogs (`pg_catalog.pg_*`) but it's not nearly as common. I frequently do the following:

1. `BEGIN` a transaction to modify the privs
2. Change ownership of `DATABASES` to a "DBA role"
3. Change ownership of `SCHEMAS` to the "DBA role"
4. `REVOKE ALL` privs on all `TABLES`, `SEQUENCES` and `FUNCTIONS` from all roles
5. `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` on relevant/appropriate tables to the appropriate roles
6. `COMMIT` the DCL transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution does not take care of function ownership following solution takes care of everything (while reviewing I noticed that it is similar to @magiconair above)

```
echo "Database: ${DB_NAME}"
echo "Schema: ${SCHEMA}"
echo "User: ${NEW_OWNER}"

pg_dump -s -c -U postgres ${DB_NAME} | egrep "${SCHEMA}\..*OWNER TO"| sed -e "s/OWNER TO.*;$/OWNER TO ${NEW_OWNER};/" | psql -U postgres -d ${DB_NAME}
# do following as last step to allow recovery
psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "ALTER DATABASE ${DB_NAME} OWNER TO ${NEW_OWNER};"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following simpler shell script worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in  `psql -U $1  -qt -c  "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname='$2'"`
do
psql -U $1 -c  "alter table $2.$i set schema $3"
done
```

Where input  $1 - username (database) 
$2 = existing schema
$3 = to new schema.

Answer (score 1):

Same as @AlexSoto's approach for functions:

```
IFS=$'\n'  
for fnc in `psql -qAt -c "SELECT  '\"' || p.proname||'\"' || '(' || pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) || ')' FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p ON p.pronamespace = n.oid WHERE n.nspname = 'public';" YOUR_DB` ; do  psql -c "alter function $fnc owner to NEW_OWNER" YOUR_DB; done
```

Answer (score 1):

**For tables you must loop that:**

```
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';" YOUR_DB` ; do  psql -U postgres -c "alter table \"$tbl\" owner to NEW_USER" YOUR_DB ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

## Docker: Modify Owner of all Tables + Sequences

```
export user="your_new_owner"
export dbname="your_db_name"

cat <<EOF | docker run -i --rm --link postgres:postgres postgres sh -c "psql -h \$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -p \$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT -U postgres -d $dbname" | grep ALTER | docker run -i --rm --link postgres:postgres postgres sh -c "psql -h \$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -p \$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT -U postgres -d $dbname"
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||schemaname||'.'||tablename||' OWNER TO $user;' FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public';
SELECT 'ALTER SEQUENCE '||relname||' OWNER TO $user;' FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'S';
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Reassign owned didn't work for me as I was wanted to change tables owned by postgres.

I ended up using Alex's method, however I wanted to do this from within psql. The following was sufficient for me.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN
    FOR rec in 
        SELECT *
        FROM pg_tables
        where schemaname = 'public'
LOOP
    EXECUTE 'alter table ' || quote_ident(rec.tablename) || ' owner to new_owner';
    END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the others discussions, that don't agree for my own problem. As said, REASSIGN OWNED don't work if owner is postgres. So, I wrote this script, inspired by discussions before :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.alt_own_onall (v_new_owner text)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $alt_own_onall$
-- ALTer OWNer ON ALL objects
DECLARE
    r           RECORD;
    v_sqlcmd    TEXT; -- commande SQL
    b_modif     BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;    -- si au moins une modif
BEGIN
    v_new_owner := quote_ident (v_new_owner);
    IF v_new_owner NOT IN
        (SELECT role_name FROM information_schema.enabled_roles WHERE role_name <>'postgres')
        THEN
            RAISE WARNING '[%] est inconnu', v_new_owner;
            RETURN;
    END IF
    ; -- tables
    RAISE INFO 'Le nouveau propriétaire des tables, vues, fonctions, schémas et de la base va être [%]', v_new_owner
    ;
    FOR r IN
        SELECT quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename) sch_tbl
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
        WHERE schemaname !~'^(pg_|information)' AND tableowner <> v_new_owner
    LOOP
        v_sqlcmd := 'ALTER TABLE ' || r.sch_tbl || ' OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';';
        RAISE INFO 'Exécution de [%]', v_sqlcmd;
        EXECUTE v_sqlcmd;
        b_modif := true;
    END LOOP
    ; -- views
    FOR r IN
        SELECT quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(viewname) v_sch_nam
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_views
        WHERE schemaname !~'^(pg_|information)' AND viewowner <> v_new_owner
    LOOP
        v_sqlcmd := 'ALTER VIEW '|| r.v_sch_nam ||' OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';';
        RAISE INFO 'Exécution de [%]', v_sqlcmd;
        EXECUTE v_sqlcmd;
        b_modif := true;
    END LOOP
    ; -- séquences
/*
    ERROR:  cannot change owner of sequence "*_seq"
    DETAIL:  Sequence "*_seq" is linked to table "*".

    FOR r IN
        SELECT quote_ident(sequence_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(sequence_name) s_sch_nam
        FROM information_schema.sequences
        WHERE sequence_schema !~'^(pg_|information)'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || r.s_sch_nam || ' OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';'
        ;
    END LOOP
    ; -- fonctions */
    FOR r IN
        SELECT
            quote_ident (n.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident (p.proname) || '(' ||
            pg_get_function_identity_arguments (p.oid) || ')' AS nsp_pro_arg
        FROM pg_proc AS p
            JOIN pg_namespace   AS n ON p.pronamespace    = n.oid
            JOIN pg_authid      AS a ON p.proowner        = a.oid
        WHERE n.nspname !~'^(pg_|information)' AND quote_ident(a.rolname) <> v_new_owner
    LOOP
        v_sqlcmd := 'ALTER FUNCTION ' || r.nsp_pro_arg || ' OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';';
        RAISE INFO 'Exécution de [%]', v_sqlcmd;
        EXECUTE v_sqlcmd;
        b_modif := true;
    END LOOP
    ; -- schémas
    FOR r IN
        SELECT quote_ident(schema_name) s_nam
        FROM information_schema.schemata
        WHERE schema_name !~'^(pg_|information)' AND quote_ident(schema_owner) <> v_new_owner
    LOOP
        v_sqlcmd := 'ALTER SCHEMA ' || r.s_nam || ' OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';';
        RAISE INFO 'Exécution de [%]', v_sqlcmd;
        EXECUTE v_sqlcmd;
        b_modif := true;
    END LOOP
    ; -- base
    FOR r IN
        SELECT d.datname, a.rolname
        FROM pg_database d JOIN pg_authid a ON d.datdba=a.oid
        WHERE d.datname=current_database() AND a.rolname <> v_new_owner
    LOOP
        v_sqlcmd := 'ALTER DATABASE ' || quote_ident(current_database()) || ' OWNER TO ' || v_new_owner || ';';
        RAISE INFO 'Exécution de [%]', v_sqlcmd;
        EXECUTE v_sqlcmd;
        b_modif := true;
    END LOOP
    ;
    IF NOT b_modif THEN RAISE INFO 'Aucune modification n''a été effectuée.'; END IF;
END
;$alt_own_onall$;
```

to use it under psql :
SELECT alt_own_onall ('new_role_name');
You have to translate messages from french to your own language.
Works on pg 9.5

Answer (score -1):

This is super easy with ansible. You may also skip `obj_type` to modify ownership of any object types.

```
- name: Reassigner owner of all objects
  postgresql_owner:
    login_user: "{{ postgres_admin_username }}"
    login_unix_socket: "{{postgres_socket}}"
    db: "db-name"
    new_owner: "new-owner"
    reassign_owned_by: "old-owner"
    obj_type: "table"
```

Here is the documentation with some further information: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/postgresql_owner_module.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Althought the following does not change the owner, but changes the role, it was what I needed to do, and when searching google I ended up on this queston, so for completeness sake I will enter this here:

For me none of the above solutions worked, I kept getting: `must be owner of relation xxx`. the final solution was:

`GRANT olduser TO newuser;`

Comment: With this command you are not altering the table's owner. Instead, you are altering newuser's role to be "olduser".

Comment: @Teodoro, thank you for that explanation, I have updated my answer.