# REASSIGN OWNED BY for 1 specified database

Tags: postgresql

I want to change owner of all tables in one particular database using

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY postgres TO myuser
```

but it shows:

```
ERROR:  cannot reassign ownership of objects owned by role postgres because they are required by the database system
```

I think it's because there are more databases in this system, but I want to reassign owners only in one specified databse (database1).

Is there a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify OWNER on all tables simultaneously in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348126/modify-owner-on-all-tables-simultaneously-in-postgresql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change owner of PostgreSql database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313323/how-to-change-owner-of-postgresql-database)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the `postgres` user owns system catalogs, you cannot reassign all objects owned by `postgres`.  You will have to sort out this situation by hand in this case.  In the future, avoid using `postgres` for non-administrative tasks.