# "ERROR: must be member of role" When creating schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, roles

I'm logged in with a superuser account and this is the process I'm doing:

```
1-> CREATE ROLE test WITH IN ROLE testroles PASSWORD 'testpasswd'
2-> CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION test
```

The role is correctly created but I'm getting this error when trying to create the Schema:

```
ERROR:  must be member of role "test"
```

Comment: just go through http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/role-membership.html

Comment: I'm still having the same problem, anyone can please help me?

Answer (score 225):

I ran into this issue when using `CREATE DATABASE` on Amazon RDS. I think it's essentially the same as using `CREATE SCHEMA`.

When using Amazon RDS, the user issuing the `CREATE DATABASE` must be a member of the role that will be the owner of the database. In my case, the superuser account I'm using is called `root`, and I'm going to create a role `o` which is going to own a database `d`:

```
postgres=> CREATE ROLE o;
CREATE ROLE

postgres=> CREATE DATABASE d OWNER = o;
ERROR:  must be member of role "o"

postgres=> GRANT o TO root;
GRANT ROLE

postgres=> CREATE DATABASE d OWNER = o;
CREATE DATABASE
```

Comment: Same thing, but I found the new user didn't need to have the CREATEDB permission. I created a regular user, granted that user role to my admin user, then created the database using the admin user with the owner set to the regular user.

Comment: There's a short write up describing the cause of this effect on RDS here.. https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/the-rds_superuser-role-isnt-that-super

Comment: I had this same error on Google Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL and this answer was the solution except I ran `GRANT o TO postgres;` before creating the database.

Comment: **WARNING** Don't forget to remove the role from `postgres` user with `REVOKE` before you enable IAM authentication for that user. Otherwise you cannot connect to the database with user `postgres` anymore until you disable IAM authentication in RDS.

Comment: RDS IAM authentication will only be affected, if the granted role `o` has the `rds_iam` role, which will be inherited by the `postgres` role.

Reason: "For PostgreSQL, if the IAM role (rds_iam) is added to a user (including the RDS master user), IAM authentication takes precedence over password authentication, so the user must log in as an IAM user."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Limitations

Answer (score 85):

I came across this same problem, it is complaining about the current(master) user you are logged in with is not a member of the user group you are trying to create the schema for.  You should grant the role access to your master user and it will let you create the SCHEMA without error:

```
GRANT <role> TO <master_user>;
```

Answer (score 24):

Are you using RDS? Because I get the same issue when I log in as the "superuser" that they create for you. The way that I was able to fix this was to create a new group role that included my super user and the user who owned the schema. So for you this would mean adding your super user and test user to a new roles group:

```
CREATE ROLE users NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
GRANT megausers TO testroles;
GRANT test TO testroles;
```

Now you should be able to create your schmea

Comment: This is a bit confused, but I did use this to eventually work out what was going on. See my response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34898033/242457

Answer (score 23):

Had this problem with RDS too.

## To solve it:

Login as superuser

```
psql --host=xxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=RDS_SUPERUSER_NAME --password --dbname=postgres
```

Create the User

```
CREATE USER newuser WITH CREATEDB PASSWORD 'password';
```

Logout

```
\q
```

Login as `newuser`

```
psql --host=xxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=newuser --password --dbname=postgres
```

Create your DB/Schema

```
CREATE SCHEMA/DATABASE ....
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't we just have to grant the admin user membership to the service role?

```
create role service_role with password 'some_password';
create database service_db with owner service_role;
ERROR:  must be member of role "service_role"
grant admin_user service_role;
GRANT ROLE
create database service_db with owner service_role;
CREATE DATABASE
```

Comment: In Postgres 9.0 and above granting includes "TO": `GRANT service_role TO admin_user;`

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this issue on RDS as well. I logged in as the `root` user, created a role named `myappuser` and then tried creating a schema called `superduper` whose owner is `myappuser`.

I found a solution which works. Create the `myappuser` role, and make sure that this role at least has the permission to create databases (the privilege is called `CREATEDB`). After creating the `myappuser` role, I logged into the database as `myappuser` and created the `superduper` schema whose user is `myappuser`. This worked without any problems.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by logging in with `postgres` user (and then apply my changes, which was changing ownership in my case):

```
sudo -u postgres psql
ALTER DATABASE my_database OWNER TO new_user;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this using Amazon RDS.

A lot of the answers are already correct, but you can also just alter the role.

Here was my implementation

`psql -h ${PGHOST} -p ${PGPORT:-5432} -U ${PGUSER:-postgres} -c "ALTER USER renderer WITH CREATEDB PASSWORD '$RENDERPASSWORD'"`

So while changing the password, I am also adding the CREATEDB role permission to the role.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. To resolve this, I logged in with the newly created role and created the database.
Somehow, grant does not work in RDS Postgres.