# ERROR: permission denied for relation tablename on Postgres while trying a SELECT as a readonly user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
```

The readonly user can connect, see the tables but when it tries to do a simple select it gets:

> ```
> ERROR: permission denied for relation mytable
> SQL state: 42501
> ```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some details about "relation mytable" ? Schema, is it a "real" table (or a view/function), triggers...

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Here is the complete solution for PostgreSQL 9+, updated recently.

```
CREATE USER readonly  WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'readonly';
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;

-- repeat code below for each database:

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE foo to readonly;
\c foo
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly; --- this grants privileges on new tables generated in new database "foo"
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to readonly; 
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
```

Thanks to https://jamie.curle.io/creating-a-read-only-user-in-postgres/ for several important aspects

If anyone find shorter code, and preferably one that is able to perform this for all existing databases, extra kudos.

Comment: does this include views?

Comment: Why are you giving the `GRANT ALL` permission by default to the readonly user?

Comment: i gave exactly as it is defined, still the sam error

Comment: can confirm rights granted using `\ddp`. Should show just `=r/` like `granting_user=r/readonly_user` for read only access.

Comment: This is verbatim SQL from the question. I do not see how it provides a solution.

Answer (score 16):

Try to add

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to readonly;
```

You probably were not aware that one needs to have the requisite permissions to a schema, in order to use objects in the schema.

Comment: Something strange is happening, I run these commands on the server using `psql` as `postgres` user and I do get a proper response, `GRANT`. Still, when I look to the ACL on the tables I see only two other accounts, one being the database owner `jirauser` and another readonly account named `qauser`. But my `readonly` does not appear there. Postgres is version 9.1 and I even restarted the server, still nothing happens.

Comment: what is/was output of \du in psql console? Can you still give this output or it's fixed already like in your answer?

Comment: I don't really know what happened, as the output was correct (GRANT).  YEsterday it did not work, but today it worked after running, again, all 3 commands.

Comment: Note: The expected respose to this is simply 'GRANT'. If you see 'WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"' then it DID NOT work. User readonly cannot grant themself extra permissions. Only a user with 'GRANT' permissions can do that so you probably need to log in as a superuser.

Comment: Hi, when i try to GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO postgres;  it responds: ERROR:  permission denied for relation databasechangeloglock. Do you know what i'm doing wrong? Thanks (it happens on GAppEngine Posgres9.6 using the public address and accessing through the terminal)

Comment: @Mike do you have permission to grant permission for that table?

Comment: Thanks a lot @sufleR

Answer (score -5):

This worked for me:

Check the current role you are logged into by using:
SELECT CURRENT_USER, SESSION_USER;

**Note**: It must match with Owner of the schema.

Schema |             Name             | Type  |     **Owner**
--------+--------+-------+----------

If the owner is different, then give all the grants to the current user role from the admin role by :

GRANT 'ROLE_OWNER' to 'CURRENT ROLENAME';

Then try to execute the query, it will give the output as it has access to all the relations now.

Comment: Changing the owner to a user called readonly hardly sounds like the right fix.

Comment: Depending on your case, wrong table owner can indeed be the cause (it was foe me). Proper way to change table ownershiip in PostgreSQL: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13535184

Answer (score -7):

make sure your user has attributes on its role. for example:

```
postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 flux      |                                                | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

after performing the following command:

```
postgres=# ALTER ROLE flux WITH Superuser;
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 flux      | Superuser                                      | {}
postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

it fixed the problem.

see tutorial for roles and stuff here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-roles-and-manage-grant-permissions-in-postgresql-on-a-vps--2

Comment: No!  Giving the Superuser role to a user called "readonly" in order to do a "select" is not the correct fix.

Comment: @Anna That's not what's happening here. This thread is not about giving read only access. This thread is about giving a user access to give another user read-only access. IMHO, this is correct. If your user is not a Superuser, you cannot create a read-only user. The error being run into is from being able to create a read-only user `ERROR: permission denied for relation mytable`

Answer (score -8):

You should execute the next query:

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE mytable TO myuser;
```

Or if your error is in a view then maybe the table does not have permission, so you should execute the next query:

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE tbm_grupo TO myuser;
```

Comment: The user is called "readonly".  It's doubtful that giving the user all permissions is the goal. He just wants to do a select.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of naming the user 'ReadOnly' if you are giving `ALTER DROP DELETE` Ect. To that user...