# GRANT SELECT Simply not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a user that I need to allow `SELECT` access to a database.  I've followed all the instructions I've found scattered all over SO and I can't get anything to work.

I've tried all the suggested solutions to all of the following links:

[How do you create a read-only user in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql)

[ERROR: permission denied for relation tablename on Postgres while trying a SELECT as a readonly user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497352/error-permission-denied-for-relation-tablename-on-postgres-while-trying-a-selec)

[Permission denied for relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520361/permission-denied-for-relation)

...and many more references to the PSQL docs, blogs and user groups.  Nothing is working.

Here are the commands I recently used as the postgres user to grant privileges:

```
postgres@dev:~$ psql
psql (9.1.9)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# grant usage on SCHEMA public to proton_read;
GRANT
postgres=# grant select on all tables in schema public to proton_read;
GRANT
postgres=# alter default privileges in schema public grant select on tables to proton_read;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
```

Here are the commands used as the read only user:

```
proton_read@dev:~$ psql proton
psql (9.1.9)
Type "help" for help.

proton=> select * from leads_lead limit 1;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation leads_lead
```

Here's the kicker, I had this working once.  I have a sample database dump that I'm using to teach basic SQL to business co-workers.  We are covering simple commands such as `SELECT`, `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` and `JOIN`.  I had an old dump and was able to grant read only access.  I dropped the database and did a pg_restore with a newer version of the database and now I cannot re-grant the SELECT access.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, every connection is to a particular database, and nearly everything you run has effect only within that one database. (One exception is that creation of users/roles themselves is global to the entire "cluster", i.e. running Postgres server.)

In the `psql` commands you show, you are connecting the first time without specifying a database (`psql`), which connects you to a database named after the current system user, which is `postgres`. This is shown at the beginning of the `psql` prompt: `postgres=#` (the `#` shows that you  are connected as a supersuser).

It is therefore only this database that is being changed by your `GRANT` statements.

Your second example uses the correct command to connect to a specific database, `psql proton`, and you can see that the prompt reflects this: `proton=>` (with the `>` replacing the `#`, since you are not connected as a superuser).

So all you need to do is run `psql proton` as your `postgres` user, and run your `GRANT` statements as superuser on that specific database. Your prompt will read `proton=#` to show you are in the right place.