# postgres read only user not working

Tags: postgresql, configuration, permissions, readonly, postgresql-9.2

I have Postgresql 9.2 with database running and now try to create a read only user. I followed these descriptions:

[ERROR: permission denied for relation tablename on Postgres while trying a SELECT as a readonly user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497352/error-permission-denied-for-relation-tablename-on-postgres-while-trying-a-selec/13511621#13511621)

[How do you create a read-only user in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760210/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-user-in-postgresql)

BasicallyI have done the following:

```
jbossmanager=# CREATE USER jbcust  WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '#######';
CREATE ROLE
jbossmanager=# GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA jbossmanager to jbcust;
GRANT
jbossmanager=# ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA jbossmanager GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO jbcust;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
jbossmanager=# GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE jbossmanager to jbcust;
GRANT
jbossmanager=# GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA jbossmanager TO jbcust;
GRANT
jbossmanager=# GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA jbossmanager TO jbcust;
GRANT
```

After this a "\l" shows the following:

```
jbossmanager=# \l
                                     List of databases
 Name     |    Owner     | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |       Access privileges
--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------
 jbossmanager | jbossmanager | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/jbossmanager             +
          |              |          |             |             | jbossmanager=CTc/jbossmanager+
          |              |          |             |             | jbcust=c/jbossmanager
```

which looks good to me, also a list of tables in that db / schema lokks fine:

```
jbossmanager=# \dp+
                                                   Access privileges
    Schema    |             Name              |   Type   |         Access privileges         | Column access privileges
--------------+-------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------
 jbossmanager | env_server_standalone_info    | table    | jbossmanager=arwdDxt/jbossmanager+|
              |                               |          | jbcust=r/jbossmanager             |
```

But now when I connect as this jbcust user to database and try:

```
#psql -d jbossmanager -U jbcust -h 127.0.0.1
Password for user jbcust:
psql (9.2.4)
Type "help" for help.

jbossmanager=> \dp+
                          Access privileges
 Schema | Name | Type | Access privileges | Column access privileges
--------+------+------+-------------------+--------------------------
(0 rows)
```

I have no idea what is wrong or what is missing.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Using the same connection settings I couldn't reproduce the error. Are you connecting with `psql` in the same way in the first example?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're connecting to the same DB on the same host?

Comment: In the first example I connected like:
# psql -d jbossmanager -U jbossmanager -h 127.0.0.1

in the second case like this:
# psql -d jbossmanager -U jbcust -h 127.0.0.1

Yes, I am sure that this is the same db on same host.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I did not see any schema when connecting with read only user is that the default schema for this user was not set.

After this:

```
ALTER USER jbcust SET search_path = jbossmanager;
```

it works perfect.

Comment: My solution ended up being a bit different from yours, but I still wanted to mention that I found this question helpful.  I had setup readonly users from several guides on the internet, but was missing

`GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA jbossmanager to jbcust;`

after this GRANT, my read only user worked perfectly.  Thank you!