# Error in cobol program on linux selecting from table in postgresql database

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, cobol, microfocus

I am new in developing Cobol programs in Linux environment.

My problem is that I create a table in PostgreSql and I am trying to connect to that table. The connection was sucessful and the `sqlcode = 0`. But, when I try to make a selection i receive the `sqlcode = -0000000007` and the message:

> SQLERRMC: ERROR: permission denied for relation minha;

`Minha` is my table. My connection string is:

`01 dsn      pic x(300) value "Driver={PostgreSQL};       - "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=orlandodb;       - "Uid=postgres;"`

Can anyone suggest how I can query the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: permission denied for relation tablename on Postgres while trying a SELECT as a readonly user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497352/error-permission-denied-for-relation-tablename-on-postgres-while-trying-a-selec).  You need to GRANT read privileges (USAGE, SELECT, etc) to the table and schema.

Comment: thanks for the response, however my table was created with the postgres user and the schema is public. it is a simple test to see how it works. the select stament is:EXEC SQL
                 SELECT cliente, numseq INTO :R-CODCLI-TCTIT,
                                             :R-NUMSEQ-TCTIT
                   FROM minha
                 WHERE cliente = '12345678'
                   AND numseq  = '000001'
            END-EXEC.

Answer (score 0):

Check your credentials, does your user have access to the db and table?

You may do it in another application like PgAdmin or alike.