# Connecting to the census public database in AWS using SQLalchemy in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy

I am taking a course in DataCamp on databases and there is a part where I access the census database in AWS using SQLalchemy.

The code is:

```
engine = \
create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://student:datacamp@postgresql.csrrinzqubik.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/census')
```

When I run this code and then try to access the data from my Jupyter Notebook I get a message that tells me that access is denied.

```
metadata = MetaData()

census = Table('census', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with = engine)

connection = engine.connect()

stmt = select([census])

stmt = stmt.where(census.columns.state == 'New York')

results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) permission denied for relation census
 [SQL: 'SELECT census.state, census.sex, census.age, census.pop2000, census.pop2008 \nFROM census \nWHERE census.state = %(state_1)s'] [parameters: {'state_1': 'New York'}]
```

I have an account in AWS.  What should I do to access the census database from my Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Doesn't the course DataCamp have a forum or Q&A where students can ask questions regarding the lectures? Perhaps someone there had the same problem and it has already been solved.

Comment: @ Edgar: Thanks for the suggestion. They have a chat area  in Slack and I have posted the question there as well.  However, this is a more general question and can be answered by the Stackoverflow community as well and perhaps better and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well...it seems to be an issue with [user permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497352/error-permission-denied-for-relation-tablename-on-postgres-while-trying-a-selec).

I have no problem either reading the column names (`census.state`, `census.sex`, `census.age`, `census.pop2000`, `census.pop2008`), or running queries on other tables:

```
>>> res = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM data')
>>> res.fetchall()
[(10, 'boobs'), (11, 'ass'), (11, 'ass'), (12, 'usa'), (12, 'usa'), (12, 'usa'), (12, 'usa'), (12, 'usa'), (12, 'usa'), (12, 'usa'), (12, 'usa'), (12, 'usa'), (12, 'usa')]
```

The [`permission denied for relation tablename` error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15522548/5535114) might be due to insufficient privileges granted for the user on the `census` table. You might want to contact the DataCamp instructor or other students there.

Comment: @ Edgar:  Thanks Edgar for your time.  As I have said I have already taken steps to contact DataCamp.  Still, since I have an AWS account and census is a public dataset open to to everyone interested, could you guide me on the steps to get access to it?