# How to alter owner of a function in postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I am writing a script to alter all functions of postgres(changing owner of each function). I am able to list down all the function names using postgres query but not able to list parameters for each of those functions.

My problem will be resolved if I get solution for any of the below mentioned problems:

1. Is there any way to list down parameters' data type in each of the function.
2. Do we have any approach to alter functions where instead of passing parameter type can  I  send some wild card.
   For Example can I write 
   ALTER FUNCTION schemaname.func(text) OWNER TO 'newowner'
   as :
   ALTER FUNCTION schemaname.func(*) OWNER TO 'newowner'.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> *Is there any way to list down parameters' data type in each of the function.*

Yes, use the `pg_get_function_identity_arguments()` function:

The following will create a SQL script to alter all functions from the `someschema` schema:

```
select 'alter function '||nsp.nspname||'.'||p.proname||'('||pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid)||') owner to newowner;'
from pg_proc p
  join pg_namespace nsp ON p.pronamespace = nsp.oid
where nsp.nspname = 'someschema';
```

You can spool the output of that into a file and then run that generated script.

If you have function names that would require quoting, you probably need to use `quote_ident` to concatenate the function names.

You can wrap all that into a function and use dynamic SQL to make life easier if you need this on a regular basis.

Comment: That particular syntax didn't work for me (PostgreSQL 9.4.8, `ERROR: syntax error at or near "'newowner'"`). I had to remove the quoting around the `''newowner''`, ie `... owner to newowner;'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but *pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid)* didn't work for me. So I replaced that function with *oidvectortypes(p.proargtypes)*.

```
select 'alter function '||nsp.nspname||'.'||p.proname||'('||oidvectortypes(p.proargtypes)||') owner to newowner;'
from pg_proc p 
join pg_namespace nsp ON p.pronamespace = nsp.oid
where nsp.nspname = 'someschema';
```