# How to find and delete some tables from PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql

In My database there are 113 Tables,

- for example i need to `drop` tables with name `ilike '%gtab%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- to get tables with name `gtab`

  ```
   select relname from pg_class where relname ilike '%gtab%'  and relname not ilike 
   '%seq%' and    relname not ilike  '%pkey%' and relname not ilike  '%idx%'
  ```
- if you want to get the `drop query`, just use `COPY` Function to export to a .CSV file and from exported csv file you can copy all your `drop` query and `execute` it as`pgScript`

  ```
  copy (select 'drop table  ' || relname || ' cascade;' from pg_class where relname  
  ilike '%gtab%'  and relname not ilike  '%seq%'and relname not ilike  '%pkey%' and 
  relname  not ilike  '%idx%' ) to'D:\DropScript.csv' with csv header
  ```

Comment: do i need to copy the entire script from exported  file and paste it to `pgAdmin` and run as pgScript ???

Comment: @user3744752  exactly !!

Comment: just a suggestion instead of using `COPY` try to make it as a function

Comment: @user3744752: You certainly do *not*  need `pgScript` for this.

Answer (score 2):

This will create the statements to drop said tables and *not* other objects matching the pattern. Also no system tables.

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || c.oid::regclass || ';'
FROM   pg_class c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace  -- to restrict to a schema
WHERE  c.relkind = 'r'                           -- only tables
AND    c.relname ILIKE '%gtab%'                  -- pattern for table names
AND    n.nspname = 'public'                      -- restrict to a schema
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The cast to `regclass` automatically escapes and schema-qualifies table names as needed and is safe against SQL injection. Details:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)

For lots of tables a single integrated statement will be faster:

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || string_agg(c.oid::regclass::text, ', ') || ';'
FROM   pg_class c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  c.relkind = 'r'
AND    c.relname ILIKE '%gtab%'
AND    n.nspname = 'public'
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Result:

```
DROP TABLE tbl1, tbl2, schema1.tbl3;
```

Related answers:

- [Is there a postgres command to list/drop all materialized views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092983/is-there-a-postgres-command-to-list-drop-all-materialized-views/23093450#23093450)
- [How to delete unused sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265540/how-to-delete-unused-sequences/8270947#8270947)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in `loop`:

```
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# do
t-# $$
t$# declare r record;
t$# begin
t$# for r in (select schemaname||'.'||tablename tn from pg_tables where tablename like '%gtab%') loop
t$#   raise info '%','dropping '||r.tn;
t$#   execute CONCAT('DROP TABLE '||r.tn);
t$# end loop;
t$# end;
t$# $$
t-# ;
INFO:  dropping public.agtab
INFO:  dropping public.bgtabb
DO
t=# rollback;
ROLLBACK
```