# How to execute a query which is stored in a table column PostgreSql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table column which contains following text data:

```
"drop table log_history_2_2015"
"drop table log_history_3_2015"
"drop table log_history_4_2015"
"drop table log_history_5_2015"
"drop table log_history_6_2015"
```

How can I execute them in single shot without looping through all these rows and executing them individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `SELECT string_agg(COLUMN_NAME,';')||chr(10)` - it will give you single line to run

Comment: Thanx for answer.what is the use of `||chr(10)` in query?

Comment: `||chr(10)` brakes single line to miltiples - adds tens ASCCI char after semicolon

Comment: Okay, Thanx for your help

Comment: @Code-Monk No worries. My pleasure

Comment: `chr(10)` is the ASCII line-feed. You can also write it as `E'\r'` in PostgreSQL. This code appends a *single* line feed at the end of the whole series of statements. If you want one after each semicolon you need to move the `||chr(10)` inside the function call. I would instead write the delimiter as `E';\r'` or simply include a literal linefeed.

Answer (score 9):

A more general solution is to use a `DO` block to execute the dynamic SQL:

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
DECLARE
  stmt text;
BEGIN
  FOR stmt IN
    SELECT statement FROM the_table
  LOOP
    EXECUTE stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Note that this runs in a single transaction.

Comment: Code-Monk asked without looping so `Do` block would be same one line for `execute`

Comment: @VaoTsun I presumed it was to avoid *client-side* looping. There is no meaningful difference between executing them in a loop in PL/PgSQL vs a multi-statement. The PostgreSQL backend just loops over the statements, exactly like you did it in PL/PgSQL, if you send a multi-statement.

Comment: Can we use this in Redshift? I wasn't able to run it until now

Comment: @GarouDan almost certainly not. Redshift is based on super ancient PostgreSQL - 8.2 IIRC.