# Change "postgres" user ownership to another user

Tags: database, postgresql, ownership

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.19.

I want to change the owner of some tables. All these tables are in the same database `my_db` in the `public` schema.

I have read the post [Modify OWNER on all tables simultaneously in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348126/modify-owner-on-all-tables-simultaneously-in-postgresql).

Thanks to this post the operation succedeed but partially.
Most of the table are owned by `postgres` user and not `new_user`.

I tried to manually change the owner but it failed.

Comment: failed with what error?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the ownership of tables owned by `postgres` if you are a superuser.

But you won't be able to `REASSIGN OWNED`, because `postgres` has to own the system objects.

Perhaps you can use `psql`'s `\gexec`:

```
SELECT format('ALTER TABLE %I SET OWNER = willi;', table_name)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE ... \gexec
```

You can fill in the appropriate `WHERE` condition.